# safe area compatible with iOS9/10/11 - programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I want to create a function to that returns a safe anchor on bottom.
When I use some like this (extension UIViewController)

```
//
var safeBottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        return view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor
    } else {
        return bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor
    }
}
```

I do not get safe area because my tabbar is overlaying my view (only iOS9/10). Can someone help with this issue? 
Usage:

```
contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeBottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: I'm assuming two things? Correct me please. (1) `bottomLayoutGuide` *should* include the tab bar *and* has worked prior to iOS 11 release. (2) this tab bar *is* part of your iOS 11 implementation. Whether or not my assumptions are correct - and please, correct them! - have you figured out the *actual* frame values along with what they should be for both iOS 11 and prior releases? Thanks.

Comment: @dfd to be perfectly honest not sure if it was working before. I use the same logic (other way around) for top area (status bar and nav bar) and it seems to be working. So I guess it should work on bottom for UITabBar since it is IUKIT component as well.

Comment: I'll supply an answer - it "indirectly" uses `safeAreaLayoutGuides` - but I think it should work for you. (It does for me. If you find it doesn't work, please, not only tell me and I'll delete the answer, but also tell me so I can make sure my apps work properly!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I do. Basically I create a clear color "safe area view" and base all my layouts on it.

In any view controller:

```
let safeAreaView = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    safeAreaView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(safeAreaView)

    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        safeAreaView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        safeAreaView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        safeAreaView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        safeAreaView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        safeAreaView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        safeAreaView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        safeAreaView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        safeAreaView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

Now if you have a view called `mySubview` and you want it 10 points below a nav bar with a height of 40, the constraint code can be:

```
    mySubview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    mySubview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    mySubview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    mySubview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

This should work in all iOS versions from iOS 9 on.

Last point - maybe your issue is merely that you are using `bottomLayoutGuide` instead of `layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor`.

Comment: Your answer is technically correct. My problem is within a modal view pushed from a custom object with TabBar and a NavBar and SnapKit. Might be long way. But thanx anyway.